# Side bar div / favorite tags jumps after load

Tags: feature-request

I'm sorry if this has already been addressed but a quick search didn't come up with anything.

The problem I'm having with the site is pretty trivial but it annoys the crap out of me. Right after the main page loads (after hitting questions) the sidebar div on the right side loads and then after a few seconds the contents of it jump up.

The biggest annoyance is that if I'm trying to click my favorites tags many times I end up missing and clicking on one of the top tags. I think this has something to do with the advertisements that appear. Is there any hope of this being fixed?

Comment: Trivial things that annoy the crap out of me are the most important things to fix, imho.

Comment: I've reloaded the page at least 30 times, and every time the content jumped *down* (after less than half a second), so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @balpha Click on the "Questions" button there should be a good chunk of white space that appears under the number of questions and above the ad that for me says "Love this site?" after about a second or so this white space is removed and the ad is pulled up to right under the questions.

Comment: @Won't I couldn't agree more :D

Comment: Not seeing that. Are you sure you're not running an ad blocker?

Comment: @balpha I don't think I am, I get the same results on Chrome 12 and IE9