# Unify the positioning of the "Favorite Tags" div across site pages

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, tag-watching

Nearly all of my SO activity involve my favorite tags. When I am done looking at a question or a tag feed, 90% of the time I want to visit a feed for one of my favorite tags.

This takes more clicks than it should because the 'Favorite Tags' div is positioned in different places on different pages.

- [Home Page](https://stackoverflow.com/): Right, above everything else
- [Questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions): Right, below one or two 'Careers' divs
- [Tag feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js): Right, below tag count, Careers, Related Tags
- [Individual Question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388733/concatenating-a-variable-string-in-jade-file/19388919#19388919): Not displayed at all ('Tagged', 'Careers', 'Related Tags' appear instead)

I generally end up going back to the home page and then clicking my desired tag. To improve usability, I suggest that the Favorite Tags feature be tweaked such that (for a logged in user) the list of favorite tags always appears at the top of the right panel on these four pages.

Similar questions that have not been resolved:
[Careers and favorites tags swap positions on main page and questions page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196788/careers-and-favorites-tags-swap-positions-on-main-page-and-questions-page)
[Side bar div / favorite tags jumps after load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101499/side-bar-div-favorite-tags-jumps-after-load)

Comment: Why would it need to appear on an individual question page?

Comment: It would be consistent with the other pages and improve site navigation for those like me who primarily want to browse their favorite tags

Comment: But the problem with that is the Favorite Tags preferences are not relevant *at all* to an individual question and it wouldn't make sense to show them there. That section isn't there to improve navigation, it's there to improve the lists of questions you're shown.

Comment: It seems inconsistent to use the right sidebar for navigation with the Favorite Tags div visible on Home, Questions, Tag Feed, but not on individual questions. Perhaps there is a more appropriate place to put the Favorite Tags div,  but in lieu of adding them site-wide (e.g. in the header), placing the div in the same place on these commonly used pages would increase the usability of the feature. (Also, surely, the Careers div does not help improve the list of questions I'm shown?)

Comment: A recent change seems to be that favourite tags now don't appear at all on individual question pages (on StackOverflow). Maybe the intent wasn't for it to be there to improve navigation, but it did. If I went 'off faves' and was looking at a question not in my faves I was one click from getting back. Now I'm two clicks. Its doubled my workload...

Comment: Well THAT sucks.